# Showing an image on my window's drag area... how can I make a click on the image still drag the window?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, interface-builder

I'm using an NSImageView to display an image on an NSWindow. The image will be on top of the area where the user can normally drag the window.

The window is styled in such a way that it's not easily apparent that you can drag the window... I thus need this little image to indicate that you *can* in fact drag the window.

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to make a click on the image drag the window! It needs this. Dragging anywhere else in the window's title area works fine.

How can I make clicking and holding the image drag the entire window?

Bonus points if you can tell me how to give the mouse a "drag icon" cursor while hovered on this image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to subclass NSImageView and return YES to mouseDownCanMoveWindow (which it inherits from NSView).

```
-(BOOL)mouseDownCanMoveWindow {
    return YES;
}
```

You can set a new cursor when the mouse enters the image view by overriding resetCursorRects like this in the NSImageView subclass (I don't know what you mean by "drag  icon" cursor, so this example uses the pointing hand cursor:

```
- (void)resetCursorRects {
    [self addCursorRect:self.bounds cursor:[NSCursor pointingHandCursor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSImageView`s have their own mouse handling. To change the way that view behaves, you will have to subclass, either `NSView` or `NSImageView`.

Comment: I should mention that I'm not committed to using NSImageView. I'll use whatever the easiest way is to display an image and have it drag the window.

Comment: Well, you can subclass `NSView` easily enough to have it do nothing but draw an image and pass mouse events up the responder chain.